# how to retrieve list of pdf files from ftp server's folder and shown it as .pdf link in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I'am using a file upload controller which uploads pdf file to ftp server by creating a folder on it. Now i need to show  this uploaded pdf files  just below the file upload controller as a link. how is it possible? how can i read all the pdf files from a particular folder on ftp server? each pdf file have different name format. my code for uploading file is here

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


      bool is_folder_exists= FtpDirectoryExists("ftp://xxx.co//"+test_id+"/"+student_id+"", userName, password);
if (is_folder_exists == true)
   {
  MessageBox.Show("Folder" + is_folder_exists);
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);

  System.Net.FtpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.co/" + test_id + "/" + student_id + "/" + filename + "");
  rq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("cccc", "xxx");
  rq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
  System.IO.Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  fs.Close();
  System.IO.Stream ftpstream = rq.GetRequestStream();
  ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  ftpstream.Close();
   }`
```

Answer (score 1):

The list command comes to rescue!

cd: to change directory on the remote machine.
ls: to list the names of the files in the current remote directory.

http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html